# Romans 15:5 is (God of patience) God the father?

Tags: romans

Romans 15:5;

> 5. Now the **God of patience** and consolation grant you to be likeminded one toward another according to Christ Jesus:

Is the **God of patience** God the father in this verse?

Comment: @NihilSineDeo The Father of the Person who came is God Father, for the Person is the only begotten Son. As to the humanity, careful words need to be selected, in conformity to the very careful wording of Matthew and Luke regarding the 'begetting' in the womb (rather than a begetting by delivery, as is the way of nature).

Comment: @NigelJ I got ahead of myself. Should have stopped half way through my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two verses, Rom 15:5, 6 answer the question easily:

> Now may the God who gives endurance and encouragement grant you
> harmony with one another in Christ Jesus, so that with one mind and
> one voice you may glorify the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ.

Note that here, Paul makes a clear distinction between "God the Father" and "our Lord Jesus Christ".

Thus, the God who gives endurance, etc, is clearly, God the Father.

Comment: Yes, indeed. (Up-voted +1.)  According to Sharp's rule τον θεον και πατερα is 'the God and Father' being the same person.